# Repository pattern using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, repository-pattern

Here is my concern,

My problem is not really with PowerShell, but the way I have to use it to implement the persistence. I often get cases where there is more than 4 commands to do the logic or to apply persistence.

For example:

When configuring a Dns Zone, I get the normal New/Get/Set/Remove-DnsZone **and** Suspend/Unsuspend-DnsZone. How my teammates are currently handling it is that they make an extra method on the repository to handle the extra commands.

It seems to me like the behavior should instead be on the object and that Suspend/Unsuspend-DnsZone should be called when Create or Update is executed on the repo.

What do you think?

---

**EDIT**
As requested, I'll put some code to demonstrate what I am talking about.

This is a fake example with an almost similar implementation of our Powershell wrapper. 
This is a method on the repository that my teammates do:

```
public void Suspend(DnsZone zone)
{
   _powerShell.Execute("Suspend-Zone", new Dictionary<string, object>{{"Name", zone.Name}});
}
```

So somewhere in your logic, to suspend a zone you have to call

```
var myZone = new DnsZone{ Name= "xyz"};
_zones.Suspend(myZone);
```

Instead, what I prone is that DnsZone should have a property or a method. So that the logic is not in the repo but in the object itself. Even though the repo has to translate that into a Suspend-Zone call.

```
var myZone = _zones.FindByName("nyname");
myZone.Suspend();
_zones.Save(myZone);
```

hth

Comment: Can you add some pseudo-code to explain this better? I'm not following you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like doing that would break a lot of the pipelining functionality that makes Powershell so easy to use from the comnmand line. If you eliminated the Suspend-DNSZone cmdlet in favor of an object method, you couldn't do

```
  get-dnszone | suspend-dnszone
```

You'd have to do

```
  get-dnszone | foreach-object {$_.suspend()}
```

Not an improvement, IMHO.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Instead of having to call the method SuspendZone(string name) on the repository, you would have a method called Suspend or even a property to handle that. Then on the Create or update of the repository the suspend-zone would be called. The problem is not within PowerShell but with the Repository pattern. Maybe I'm not clear with the way I wrote it.